# std::tie vs std::make_tuple

Tags: c++, tuples

[This code compiles](http://ideone.com/bGk17H) but I'm wondering which version should be preferred:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

tuple<int, int, int> return_tuple1() {
    int a = 33;
    int b = 22;
    int c = 31;
    return tie(a, b, c);
}

tuple<int, int, int> return_tuple2() {
    int a = 33;
    int b = 22;
    int c = 31;
    return make_tuple(a, b, c);
}

int main() {
    auto a = return_tuple1();
    auto b = return_tuple2();
    return 0;
}
```

since the function is returning a tuple by value there shouldn't be any problem in using `std::tie` right? (i.e. no dangling references)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Be very careful with `std::tie`. Returning a `tie` is logically equivalent to returning a reference, with all of the caveats that come with it.

Logically, these three are equivalent:

```
int& foo();
std::reference_wrapper<int> foo();
std::tuple<int&> foo();
```

and this:

```
int a = 10;
return std::tie(a);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
int a = 10;
return std::ref(a);
```

because it produces one of these:

```
std::tuple<int&>
```

In your example you are saved by the return value's implicit conversion. However, replacing the return type with `auto` reveals the logic error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

auto return_tuple1() {  // function name is now lying
    int a = 33;         // it should be return_chaos()
    int b = 22;
    int c = 31;
    return tie(a, b, c);
}

auto return_tuple2() {
    int a = 33;
    int b = 22;
    int c = 31;
    return make_tuple(a, b, c);
}

int main() {
    auto a = return_tuple1(); // uh-oh...

    auto b = return_tuple2();

    std::get<0>(a); // undefined behaviour - if you're lucky you'll get a segfault at some point.
    std::get<0>(b); // perfectly ok
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get the first part of your answer. Some novice questions: Are `int&` and `std::tuple<int&>` the same? I thought std::tuple as some kind of "container", but if there is only one element in std::tuple, it is not a container anymore? So, both `std::tie(a)` and `std::ref(a)` produces one of `int&`, `std::reference_wrapper<int>`, or `std::tuple<int&>` and these three are equivalent types?

Comment: They are not exactly equivalent, but they are logically equivalent. `int&` is an object that is a reference to an int. `tuple<int&>` is an object that contains a reference to an int. i.e. they do the same job. (but the syntax to access that int is a litle different in each case)

Answer (score 18):

`std::tie` won't do what you think it does.
`std::tie` returns a `tuple` of **references** to the elements passed, so in `return_tuple1()`, what actually happens is :

```
tuple<int, int, int> return_tuple1() {
    int a = 33;
    int b = 22;
    int c = 31;
    return std::tuple<int&,int&,int&>(a,b,c);
}
```

then, the return type `tuple<int, int, int>` **builds itself** from `std::tuple<int&,int&,int&>`.

now, the compiler *might* optimize this construction away, but I wouldn't bet on that. use `std::make_tuple` as it is the right tool for that task.

Comment: Also `std::make_tuple` better expresses the intent of the code. If I saw that code calling `std::tie` and then storing it in a `tuple` I'd likely think that was a bug.

Answer (score 3):

`tuple2` should be more efficient.  `tie` does create a `tuple` but the thing you have to remember about `tie` is that it does not make a tuple of type `Args...` but instead makes a tuple of type `Args&...` meaning your return type and your tuple do not match.  That means you need to copy from the tied tuple to the return tuple.

In the second example you are returning a tuple with the same type as the return type so you can return that directly.  You do not have to copy there.

Comment: Returning a reference to a local variable is always a bug. The save here is that a tuple of values is still created due to implicit conversion to the return type.